# Unable to change font for web page

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, fonts

Trying to set an external font for the entire body but no changes occurs. The font file is in the correct location. Tested with other fonts that is present such as Times New Roman and font doesn't change either.

I am using bootstrap but calling my custom css file after bootstrap thus I believe it should override bootstrap. I have other custom css in that same file which is executing other codes correctly. To play it safe I called font-family with !important and no changes either. What is wrong here.

```
<!-- html page to show how I place my css files. -->
<head>
    <title>A Title</title>
    <!-- Jquery -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Custom Files -->
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
    <script src="js/scripts.js"></script>
</head>  

/*styles.css file*/

@font-face {
    font-family: "KenzoCustom";
    src: url(kenzo-regular.otf);
}

body{
    background-color: #eaeaf4;
    /*font-family: "Times New Roman", Times, serif;*/ /*No change either*/
    font-family: KenzoCustom, serif; 
}

<!-- Working Code -->
@font-face {
    font-family: KenzoCustom;
    src: url('../fonts/kenzo-regular.otf');
}

body{
    background-color: #eaeaf4;
    font-family: KenzoCustom, serif;
}
```

Comment: is the kenzo .otf file in the same dir as your .css file? REmember that urls paths in external .css files are relative to the location of the css file, NOT the html file that's loading the css.

Comment: @MarcB Above way= the font file is inside the css folder. Also followed the exact url for bootstrap fonts and placed mine instead as follows: url(../fonts/kenzo-regular.otf); Same result. It is not working even for other default fonts like Times New Roman.

Comment: then check your browser's debug console for errors. maybe there's a css syntax error somewhere, or the css file isn't being loaded in the first place.

Comment: You need to put your custom font inside quotes!(I'm pointing to the body selector)

Comment: this might not matter, but can you try it with quotes `font-family: "KenzoCustom", serif; `.

Comment: @HTMLNoob Able to use it without quotes.

Comment: @MarcB Edited above to show working code. To note, I had no errors when I inspect, and the code that is working now did not work 5 minutes ago. I didn't do anything different. Am clueless as to how it is even working now.

Comment: clear your cache when you make a change and it doesnt show up.

Answer (score 0):

sometimes parent css applied on that you have to use 
font-family: "KenzoCustom", serif !important;